# Ways to bend a track and props nicely?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, vertex-shader

This is my very first gamedev question, please be gentle with a learning unity noob.

So i have this runner-game project where i'd would like the track to be bent and twisted like in [this Thumper trailer](https://youtu.be/ZldpPwt-Owo?t=15)  with the [twisted corridor effect](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/abstract-d-background-twisted-corridor-sky-44350927.jpg) in addition. But i'm not very good with complex calculations.

Actually in my project, the levels have a track with defined length. The track is a straight game object composed by several straight prefabs sections of 500units and props within. The entire track is bent with a hlsl shader from the camera position to the furthest vertex point with script found on the web :

```
#include "UnityCG.cginc"


struct appdata
{
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

struct v2f
{
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
    float4 color : TEXCOORD2;
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
};

sampler2D _MainTex;
float4 _MainTex_ST;
float _CurveStrengthY;
float _CurveStrengthX;
float _CurveTwist;

v2f vert(appdata v)
{
    v2f o;

    float _Horizon = 100.0f;
    float _FadeDist = 50.0f;


    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

    float dist = UNITY_Z_0_FAR_FROM_CLIPSPACE(o.vertex.z);

    o.vertex.y -= _CurveStrengthY * dist * dist * _ProjectionParams.x;

    o.vertex.x -= _CurveStrengthX * dist * dist * _ProjectionParams.x;
    
    // how tf do i add twist
    
    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);

    o.color = v.color;

    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o, o.vertex);
    return o;
}

fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    // sample the texture
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * i.color;

    // apply fog
    UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
return col;
}
```

controlled by this script where i added random values to the bends to see changes for testing purposes :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class WorldCurver : MonoBehaviour
{

    float lerpDuration = 500f;

    float startValue=-0.004f;
    float endValue=0.004f;

    float randomTime = 0;

    [Range(-0.005f, 0.002f)]
    public float curveY = 0.01f;

    [Range(-0.006f, 0.006f)]
    public float curveX = 0.01f;


    [Range(0f, 360f)]
    public float curveAngle = 0.01f;

    int m_CurveStrengthID_Y;
    int m_CurveStrengthID_X;
    int m_CurveTwistID;

    private void OnEnable()
    {

        m_CurveStrengthID_Y = Shader.PropertyToID("_CurveStrengthY");
        m_CurveStrengthID_X = Shader.PropertyToID("_CurveStrengthX");
        m_CurveTwistID = Shader.PropertyToID("_CurveTwist");
    

    }

    void Start() {

        StartCoroutine(bendPath());

    }

    IEnumerator bendPath()
    {
        while(true){

            float randomTime = Mathf.Round(Random.Range(lerpDuration,lerpDuration * 1.2f));
        
            float timeElapsed = 0;


            Debug.Log("Bending path in " + randomTime);

            float nextBendY = Random.Range(-0.0012f,0.001f);
            float nextBendX = Random.Range(-0.001f,0.001f);

            while (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
            {
                curveY = Mathf.Lerp(curveY, nextBendY, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                curveX = Mathf.Lerp(curveX, nextBendX, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                timeElapsed += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

                yield return null;
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(lerpDuration);

        }

    }



    void Update()
    {       

        Shader.SetGlobalFloat(m_CurveStrengthID_Y, curveY);
        Shader.SetGlobalFloat(m_CurveStrengthID_X, curveX);
        Shader.SetGlobalFloat(m_CurveAngleID, curveAngle);

    
    }
}
```

The materials that uses the shader makes [it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1jNX.png)

I wanted to CurveStrengthX and CurveStrengthY to be separately exposed in order to be changed over time to make it look like a road with turns that you can see coming. It works, the track is bent, but my goal here is to make it look like a road. When i make the CurveStength values changes it looks more like a bent treadmill belt scrolling at you than a road. Plus i can't add twists on it at some point of the track.

The ship goes straight in Z axis and you can strafe left to right with a variable speed. It's independent from the track, kept at a fixed value in Y to make the illusion it floats over the ground since the shader makes the track straight again in front of the camera. The camera is fixed to the ship with an offset.

So my question is, is there any good way to bend and twist the complete track, see the coming turns and make the illusion to navigate along ?

I would like to avoid :

- to make more turn prefabs in all directions and lengths for road sections because of the world axes rotations. I'd like to only move the ship along the Z axis in a seamless track when possible.
- to rewrite my movement / input system

Ideas i thought that would do the job :

- to add to the shader, a succession of bends and twists over the track in order to keep the original level and props models straight (easier for me to adjust and tweak over the levels)
- to use the shadergraph to rewrite the shader with bending and twists sequence
- rewrite the entire shader
- maybe use a spline or something to bend the track along
- completely abandon multiple bendings and twists (but i hope not)